# Have a WebAPI Controller send an http request to another REST service

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm creating WebAPI service, and I want it to redirect all incoming requests (GET,POST) to an external REST service and return the response (Json/html) to the original request to my WebAPI.

What is the best way to go about doing this? HttpResponseMessage or HttpWebResponse

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/Geocoder")]
    public HttpWebResponse GetCandidates(string query)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://externalRestService.com/arcgis/rest/services/Geocode" + query);

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        return response;

    }
```

I also tried

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient()
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(""https://externalRestService.com/arcgis/rest/services/Geocode")
            };

            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            response = httpClient.GetAsync(requestUrl).Result;
            return response;
        }
        catch
        {
            return new HttpResponseMessage()
            {
                StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError,
                ReasonPhrase = "Internal Server Error"
            };
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance for any help. I'm newbie at .Net Core and webapis

Comment: Don't create a new HttpClient with each call to your API action; this pattern is a known issue with using HttpClient (you will eventually run out of available socket handles).  Create a static or singleton HttpClient and reuse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach worked for me.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GET(string query)
    {
        string _apiUrl = "http://foo.com/rest/services/Geocode?"; 
        string _baseAddress = "http://foo.com/rest/services/Geocode?";

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(_baseAddress);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            var responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(_apiUrl + query);

            if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
                response.Content = responseMessage.Content;
                return ResponseMessage(response);
            }
        }
        return NotFound();
    }
```